# How to run an Automator Workflow/Service from Cocoa app?

Tags: swift, cocoa, service, workflow, automator

So I tried learning Swift well enough to recreate my programs in it, didn't work so well and I didn't get very far. Tried running my C++ functions from Obj-C++ source by calling the functions, didn't work and the project refused to open again after the first time I closed it. I don't find object oriented programming very intuitive in the first place so I'd like to avoid Obj-C.

I already have both an Automator standalone workflow and a Service (that do the same thing) which is get the programs I need, display confirmation, run the program in a terminal window with stdout, and display a notification before exiting. This is everything I need it to do when a specific button is pressed.

So how would I go about linking this button to an Automator `func run()` block in Swift? I know the command that needs to be used but like I said I don't find object oriented programming very intuitive so I need to know the context in which that function is used. Would following block be enough in practice or would it need more specification?

```
@IBOutlet weak var testButton(NSButton!)
@IBAction testButton(_ sender: AnyObject)
  {
   let guard Bundle.main.path(forName: "test",forType:"workflow")
   else
     {
      print("Could not find 'test.workflow'")
      return
     } 
   let URL="//location of file"
   class func run(at: URL, withInput: nil)
  }
```

Am I missing something about how to do this or is the above enough? Secondarily can someone please give an example as to the format of a file URL where the file is located in the bundles "Resources" folder?
Also would the `class` remain the word class or should I be specifying a custom class? Can someone please give me a realworld example of this block/concept in practice?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `testButton` function that should work:

```
@IBAction func testButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let workflowPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "workflow") else {
        print("Workflow resource not found")
        return
    }

    let workflowURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: workflowPath)
    do {
        try AMWorkflow.run(at:workflowURL, withInput: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Error running workflow: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. You need to `import Automator` at the top of your source file in order for the Swift compiler to recognize the `AMWorkflow` class
2. You need to add test.workflow to your project